# Fedora 31 drops wifi connection after some time

Tags: fedora, wifi, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

I'm using Fedora 31 on my Notebook. Everything works well, except for Fedora dropping the wifi connection after a while, making it necessary to reconnect to the network. Every few minutes after reconnecting the behaviour repeats itself. I have no idea whats the reasons for that. It often happens when I downlaod files (putting "load" on the network) but sometimes also without any obvious reason. The problem first appeared under Fedora 30 and stayed after the upgrade to Fedora 31.

Output for journalctl -b -u  NetworkManager:

```
-- Logs begin at Sun 2019-07-14 01:05:47 CEST, end at Sat 2019-11-16 23:42:15 CET. --
Nov 16 23:35:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Nov 16 23:35:19 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943719.8189] NetworkManager (version 1.20.6-1.fc31) is starting... (after a restart)
Nov 16 23:35:19 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943719.8191] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 20-connectivity-fedora.conf)
Nov 16 23:35:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Nov 16 23:35:19 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943719.8260] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Nov 16 23:35:19 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943719.8355] manager[0x5559cd8e80f0]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3382] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3385] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "localhost.localdomain"
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3390] dns-mgr[0x5559cd8cd240]: init: dns=default,systemd-resolved rc-manager=symlink
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3401] rfkill2: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/0000:05:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill2) (driver ath10k_pci)
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3403] manager[0x5559cd8e80f0]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3403] manager[0x5559cd8e80f0]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3479] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib64/NetworkManager/1.20.6-1.fc31/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3486] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib64/NetworkManager/1.20.6-1.fc31/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3511] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib64/NetworkManager/1.20.6-1.fc31/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3553] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib64/NetworkManager/1.20.6-1.fc31/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3559] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib64/NetworkManager/1.20.6-1.fc31/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3561] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3563] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3565] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3567] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3644] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifcfg-rh ("/usr/lib64/NetworkManager/1.20.6-1.fc31/libnm-settings-plugin-ifcfg-rh.so")
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3644] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3838] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3845] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3886] manager: (enp4s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3951] settings: (enp4s0): created default wired connection 'Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1'
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.3986] device (enp4s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.4067] device (wlp5s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.4079] manager: (wlp5s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.4127] device (wlp5s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943720.7252] device (wlp5s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 96:1B:95:D7:6D:B2 (scanning)
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.0023] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.0103] manager: (virbr0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.0157] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.0157] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: init -> starting
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.0323] manager: (virbr0-nic): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.0446] device (virbr0-nic): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.0458] device (virbr0-nic): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.0583] sup-iface[0x5559cd8fe130,wlp5s0]: supports 5 scan SSIDs
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.0596] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.0597] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp5s0 created
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.0599] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.0602] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.0610] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.0613] device (wlp5s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <warn>  [1573943721.0631] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.3859] device (virbr0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.3906] device (virbr0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.3924] device (virbr0): Activation: starting connection 'virbr0' (dc059138-81a5-4d0a-bb5e-725c891ae6bf)
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.3935] device (virbr0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.3947] device (virbr0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.3976] device (virbr0-nic): Activation: starting connection 'virbr0-nic' (d3fd587b-3b1e-418f-9fa9-dc52709be3e1)
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.3980] device (virbr0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.3991] device (virbr0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4045] device (virbr0-nic): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4060] device (virbr0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4066] device (virbr0-nic): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4073] device (virbr0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4083] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4108] device (virbr0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4127] device (virbr0-nic): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4203] device (virbr0): bridge port virbr0-nic was attached
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4203] device (virbr0-nic): Activation: connection 'virbr0-nic' enslaved, continuing activation
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4214] device (virbr0-nic): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4270] device (virbr0-nic): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4274] device (virbr0-nic): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4291] device (virbr0-nic): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4363] device (virbr0-nic): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4374] device (virbr0): bridge port virbr0-nic was detached
Nov 16 23:35:21 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943721.4374] device (virbr0-nic): released from master device virbr0
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7709] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wifi-SSID' (b11eeab9-1cd2-40cf-b02e-719ac7a2cbcb)
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7722] device (wlp5s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wifi-SSID' (b11eeab9-1cd2-40cf-b02e-719ac7a2cbcb)
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7731] device (wlp5s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7741] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7777] device (wlp5s0): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to 58:00:E3:D0:B5:0F (preserve)
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7887] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> disabled
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7889] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: ready -> disabled
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7892] device (wlp5s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7897] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Wifi-SSID' has security, but secrets are required.
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7898] device (wlp5s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7901] sup-iface[0x5559cd8fe130,wlp5s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7939] device (wlp5s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7946] device (wlp5s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7950] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Wifi-SSID' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7952] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Wifi-SSID'
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7952] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7953] Config: added 'bssid' value '54:67:51:B8:29:2A'
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7954] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7955] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7982] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: disabled -> inactive
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.7982] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: disabled -> inactive
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.8098] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Nov 16 23:35:25 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943725.8099] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.5410] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.5412] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.5617] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.5618] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.6162] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.6162] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.6367] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.6367] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.7563] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.7564] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "Wifi-SSID"
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.7564] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.7651] device (wlp5s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.7656] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.8962] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.8970] device (wlp5s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.8993] device (wlp5s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.8995] device (wlp5s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.9002] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.9017] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.9018] policy: set 'Wifi-SSID' (wlp5s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.9062] device (wlp5s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov 16 23:35:30 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943730.9069] manager: startup complete
Nov 16 23:35:31 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943731.0336] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov 16 23:35:32 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943732.0747] policy: set 'Wifi-SSID' (wlp5s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Nov 16 23:35:34 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573943734.5034] agent-manager: req[0x5559cd9eb540, :1.201/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Nov 16 23:40:47 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573944047.5176] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
```

The general journal shows the following before dropping the connection:

```
Nov 16 23:40:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1626]: Starting Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager...
Nov 16 23:40:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1626]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
Nov 16 23:40:47 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573944047.5176] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Nov 16 23:40:47 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov 16 23:40:47 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov 16 23:40:47 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Nov 16 23:40:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Nov 16 23:40:57 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Nov 16 23:41:11 localhost.localdomain tracker-store[3088]: OK
Nov 16 23:41:11 localhost.localdomain systemd[1626]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
```

I also get the following error during the creation-phase of the connection:

```
    Nov 16 23:43:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov 16 23:43:08 localhost.localdomain kernel: wlp5s0: deauthenticating from 54:67:51:b8:29:2a by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Nov 16 23:43:08 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[1183]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=54:67:51:b8:29:2a reason=3 locally_generated=1
Nov 16 23:43:08 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[1183]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Nov 16 23:43:08 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <warn>  [1573944188.6104] sup-iface[0x5559cd8fe130,wlp5s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Nov 16 23:43:08 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573944188.6110] device (wlp5s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 16 23:43:08 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[1183]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Nov 16 23:43:08 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573944188.6136] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Nov 16 23:43:08 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1573944188.6136] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): state changed bound -> done
Nov 16 23:43:08 localhost.localdomain wpa_supplicant[1183]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=DE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable NetworkManager's wireless power management. Create a file:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/wifi-powersave-off.conf
```

Enter the following contents to the file:

```
[connection]
# Values are 0 (use default), 1 (ignore/don't touch), 2 (disable) or 3 (enable).
wifi.powersave = 2
```

Restart NetworkManager:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Or you can edit your wi-fi connection to set powersave off:

```
nmcli con mod your_connection_name 802-11-wireless.powersave 2
```

If it didn't help, you can try to set BSSID, IP and Gateway for your connection clearly. As a last resort, you can replace NetworkManager with wicd or with systemd-networkd + wpa_supplicant.

Also, maybe your bluetooth and wifi work on the same frequencies. Turn off bluetooth temporarily.

Answer (score -1):

> "/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/wifi-powersave-off.conf" E212: Could not
> open the file to write to

when i try to save the file it sends this

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/425044)